# Tracking position on google maps via GPS

Tags: java, google-maps, gps

I'm working on a project, which is basically to track a person in real-time via GPS. His position has to be updated at all times on Google maps (or any other). Here is how it looks like:

1. We are already set to receive the co-ordinates of the person (via GPS).
2. We want the maps available offline. (We're receiving GPS co-ordinates (X,Y) through a wire so lack of internet won't be a problem in that aspect).
3. Then we code in Java, such that the map is visible to us and the position of the person is marked by a dot (or circle).

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to download the Google maps (or any other) and then work on them to achieve what I've mentioned?
2. I'll be making the framework in swing. But for the dot-action, which other components will be required?
3. How will be the co-ordinates that I receive from GPS, interpreted on the maps? I mean in code I'll have to tell the program where to draw the dot, right? As of now I'm thinking, I'll program the position of the dot, such that (co-ordinates received from GPS = co-ordinates on google maps). But I've a feeling it won't be as simple. So please guide how can this be achieved.

Answer (score 1):

1. From my research, no. It is not possible. The only 'offline' features is offline map caching INSIDE the Google Maps App for iOS and Android. If you're on Windows, you may want to try [these applications that claim they can grab the maps](http://softadvice.informer.com/I_Want_To_Use_Offline_Map_On_Pc.html). I'm on OSX, so I can't test them.
2. Since you'll have the offline map (a folder with an HTML), in Swing you will simply create a `Browser` component (it exists in SWT, don't know if they are in Swing too). The browser should have APIs like `setUrl` or/and `setHtml`. You will extract the HTML from the maps, **draw** the dots directly in the HTML code (with JavaScript), then include the resulting HTML in the Swing browser.
3. This is the easiest part. You can draw on the map with JavaScript (with `GoogleMarker` components - google it). When you instantiate those markers, you pass a latitude and a longitude from your GPS. Then the map will know where to draw them.